# Typescript generic constraint extends other generic type

Tags: generics, typescript, type-safety

I would like to create a reusable network service component, which would be responsible for CRUD requests of an `Item`.

Let"s say my `CatService` want to request a list of `cats`, then it can have a `restService` instance and it can use it for list, create, update, delete...:

```
private restService:RestListService<Cat[]> = RestListService();
...
restService.list(urlToGetCats).then(cats => console.log(listdata));
...
restService.update(urlToUpdateACat, updatedCat);
```

I implemented this generic components, but it not safe enough. The class declaration looks like:

```
export class RestListService<T extends Array<Identifiable>> {

    private dataSubject$: BehaviorSubject<T> = null;

    list(url: string): Promise<T> { }

    // PROBLEM: I cannot specify the `savingInstance` & the returned Promise type: 
    update(updateURL: string, savingInstance: Identifiable): Promise<Identifiable> { }

}
```

Ideally, I would do something like introduce a generic `V` as the type of the items in the array to make the array (and the whole class) more typesafe:

```
export class RestListService<T extends Array<V extends Identifiable>> {

    //Here the Promise is type safe:
    update(updateURL: string, savingInstance: Identifiable): Promise<V> { }

}
```

But it's not permitted at the moment (as I see).

Can I somehow solve the type safety in this situation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
export class RestListService<V extends Identifiable, T extends Array<V>> {

    //Here the Promise is type safe:
    update(updateURL: string, savingInstance: Identifiable): Promise<V> { }

}
```